# <p:selectOneMenu listener method returns null when a value is selected

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using JSF 2.0 with Primefaces 3.4.2

I have the following in JSF page

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{mb.employee}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{mb.employeeList}" var="emp"
    itemLabel="#{emp.employeeName}" itemValue="#{emp.employeeCode}"/>
    <p:ajax listener="#{mb.changeMethod}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Problem is when I select a value in selectOneMenu, I am getting null in changeMethod of ManagedBean, for this `System.out.println("val  "+employee.getEmployeeName());`

What could be the reason for this? How can I resolve this problem?
Any hep is highly appreciable.

**ManagedBean** Code

```
@Named("mb")
@ViewAccessScoped
public class MyBean implements Serializable {

private Employee employee;
private List<Employee> employeeList;

@Inject
EmployeeService employeeService;

@PostConstruct
public void loadEmployees() {
employeeList = employeeService.getEmployees();
}


public void changeMethod() {
System.out.println("val  "+employee.getEmployeeName());
}


/* getters and setters for employee and employeeList */
.... methods
/* */
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are not specifying on the `<p:ajax>` component which form elements to process, so the ajax request may be submitting multiple values that could be conflicting with other field validation.  Remmeber that if a value is submitted and it fails validation, then none of the request values get set to the model.  When you reach the Application(Event) phase, the model values will not reflect any submitted request values.

Try this:

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{mb.employee}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{mb.employeeList}" var="emp"
    itemLabel="#{emp.employeeName}" itemValue="#{emp.employeeCode}"/>
    <p:ajax process="@this" partialSubmit="true" listener="#{mb.changeMethod}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Above you will be submitting just the current component request value to be applied to the model.

**EDIT:**

Actually it probably isn't a validation issue so much as there are no request values being submitted on the ajax event.

According to the Primefaces Manual:

> process   null    String Component(s) to process in partial request.
>
> update    null    String Component(s) to update with ajax.

The second column is Default Value.  In the standard `<f:ajax>` the `execute` attribute defaults to `@this` however this is not the case for `<p:ajax>`.  If you want to submit the current component then you must specify this in the `process` attribute.

Comment: I have added `<p:ajax process="@this" partialSubmit="true"`, then `changeMethod is not getting invoked. When I tried only with `process="@this"`. then I am getting `null pointer exception`.

Comment: @Polppan There must be a null pointer occurring in your property setter or getter methods.  This could also be occurring in the `converter` for your `selectOneMenu` component.  You are converting `employee` objects aren't you?

Comment: Is this because I do not have converter class? Yes employeeList and employee are Basically Employee class.

Comment: @Polppan Yes you will need to implement a converter for objects that you bind directly to `selectOneMenu`.

Comment: I will add a converter class and will get back to you.

Comment: @maple_shaft is right, object type  bind to itemValue is String and object type bind to selectOneMenu value is Employee. It mismatch, a converter could solve the issue

Comment: Or simplier, if you do not need this converter elsewhere, bind the selectOneMenu value to a String

Comment: @maple_shaft I have added a Converter class, however when I try to run application I am getting `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`

Comment: @Polppan Hmmm... perhaps you can post a seperate question and post the markup and converter code and I will take a look.

Comment: @maple_shaft I have already, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14996601/converter-class-throwing-exception-java-lang-illegalargumentexception

Comment: @maple_shaft I have resolved `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` issue. However still I am getting NPE in `changeMethod` though.

Comment: @Polppan That must mean your value isn't getting set at the bean.  What version of Primefaces are you using?  I somehow remember there was a bug with the Primefaces selectOneMenu component where converters didn't work correctly... I suggest trying to use `<h:selectOneMenu>` and `<f:ajax execute="@this" render="..." listener="..." />` instead of Primefaces.  Still use the same selectItems and converter.  Let me know what happens.

Comment: @maple_shaft I am using PF 3.4.2 version. Another thing is Converter class `getAsObject` is not getting called. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: @maple_shaft I tried as yoy suggested by changing to <h:selectOneMenu> and <f:ajax , however still I am getting NPE.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add converter to **p:selectOneMenu** to let it know that you are dealing with **employee object**. Create the converter class and use it with **converter** attribute. Here is the sample converter.

```
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;
import javax.faces.convert.FacesConverter;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Configurable;

@FacesConverter("employeeConverter")
@Configurable
public class EmployeeConverter implements Converter {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeService employeeService;

    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
            String value) {
        if (value == null || value.length() == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        Long id = Long.parseLong(value);
        return employeeService.findUser(id);
    }

    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
            Object value) {
        return value instanceof Employee ? ((Employee) value).getId().toString() : "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Chris Any reason why `getAsObject` method not being called? Only `getAsString` method is only called?

Comment: **getAsObject** is called when the data is saved. At that time, **selectOneMenu** must return the required object to save. **getAsString** is called for UI conversion only to see name or code or something like that.

Comment: Chris before saving is there any way we can test whether `getAsObject' is return correct value?

Comment: I think **getAsObject** will be called only when the object needs to be retrieved for saving. I'm not sure it will be called at any other stage. Maybe it is the default behavior of **javax.faces.convert.Converter**.

Comment: getAsObject method gets invoked when partial update happens too, something like `<p:ajax update`. Thanks