# How to get other component value from p:ajax listener when I click on p:tree

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have a problem and I need your helps!!! I want to get selected value of p:selectOneListbox when I click on a tree, but the value is always null, even though I clicked on p:selectOneListbox first. Here is my xhtml code:

```
<h:form>
<p:selectOneListbox id="selectRole"
            value="#{grandUseAuthoritiesBean.selectedRoleId}"               
            filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains">
            <f:selectItems value="#{grandUseAuthoritiesBean.roleList}"
                var="role" itemLabel="#{role.code}" itemValue="#{role.roleId}" />
</p:selectOneListbox>
<p:tree value="#{grandUseAuthoritiesBean.root}"
                selectionMode="single" var="node"
                style="font-size:13px; width:100%;border-width:0">
                <p:treeNode icon="ui-icon-calculator">
                    <h:outputText value="#{node}" />
                </p:treeNode>
                <p:ajax event="select" update="@([id$=privilegeChecbox])"
                    listener="#{grandUseAuthoritiesBean.onNodeSelect()}">
                </p:ajax>
            </p:tree>
</h:form>
```

and here is my manage bean's code:

```
public String selectedRoleId;
public String getSelectedRoleId() {
    return selectedRoleId;
}
public void setSelectedRoleId(String selectedRoleId) {
    this.selectedRoleId = selectedRoleId;
}
public void onNodeSelect(NodeSelectEvent event) {
    if (selectedRoleId!=null)
     System.out.println("selected Role Id: "+ this.selectedRoleId);
}
```

I can't print the variable "selectedRoleId" coz it is null but if I use a button'method to call this variable, I can get its value. What should I do? Thanks for reading my question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is when you choose something from listbox it is not visible inside backing bean until you send a form or do a partial sending so hence null value. Add partial processing to `<p:selectOneListbox>` and check again:

`<p:ajax process="@this" partialSubmit="true" />`

Also similar topic:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14988129/3803447